# Openni_launch Error

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> [ERROR] [1323210464.780630833]: Unable
> to open camera calibration file
> [/home/turtlebot/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00366913112050A.yaml]
> [ WARN] [1323210464.780840076]: Camera
> calibration file
> /home/turtlebot/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00366913112050A.yaml
> not found. [ WARN]
> [1323210464.789039472]: Using default
> parameters for RGB camera calibration.
> [ WARN] [1323210464.789295719]: Using
> default parameters for IR camera
> calibration.calibration.

Can anyone explain to me the above error message?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12241/openni_launch-error/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Launch file is looking for a calibration file in specified path and which is not available.

This question is already open
http://answers.ros.org/question/2891/ros-kinect-roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch

You can use the following which works fine for me, if it serves your purpose.

```
roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-06**:
In the trunk it isn't an error anymore. Just a warning, so I assume it will eventually appear in the debs.